# Boost: How to serialize/deserialize a generic type collection through a base pointer when types is missing?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm building a data structure that can contain arbitrary type pairs (key, value) which will be stored and serialized through a base pointer. This data structure will be used between peers in a network and I can't make any guarantee that all type pairs exist on the receiving end. Boost can serialize a collection just fine but if an entry can't be serialized it will throw an exception and the deserialization will abort. In my case that is considered normal and that entry should be discarded and the deserialization should proceed.

What solutions exist for continuing deserialization if an entry in a collection fails?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that exists is /versioning/

The `serialize` interface passes an unsigned `version` number to your classes' deserialize method, so you can decide how handle things if your client happens to be an older version (i.e. don't know a few types) or newer (i.e. know about a few types).

If you're doing a plain polymorphic container, you'll want to do manual serialization that encodes the version information with each element, in a way, so client are able to skip the element before "crashing"